# subcategory will not fill on the dropdownbox using php mysql ajex

Tags: php

my problem is when I select the category from the drop-down box. relevant subcategory will display in the below drop-down box. but category fills on the drop-down box successfully.but when I select the category from the drop-down box
relevant subcategory doesn't display. I wrote the coding below what I tried so far.please anyone helps me to solve this problem. thank you

```
**Ajax**

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function())
        {
            $('#cat').on('change',function()
            {
                var cat_id = $(this).val();
                if(cat_id)
                {
                    $.get(
                        "ajex.php",
                        {cat_id:cat_id},
                        function(data)
                        {
                            $('#subcat').html(data);

                        }
                    );
                }else {
                    $('#subcat').html('<option> errrr</option>')
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <select name="cat" class="form-control"  id="cat">
        <option> Select  a Product Category </option>

**view.php**
    <?php

        $get_cat = "select * from categories ";

        $run_cat = mysqli_query($con,$get_cat);
        while ($row_cat=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat))
        {
            $cat_id = $row_cat['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row_cat['cat_title'];
            echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>

**ajex.php**

    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && !empty($_GET['cat'])) {
            include("includes/db.php");
            $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];
            $query = "select * from bass_categories where cat_id= '$cat_id' ";
            $do = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($do);

            if ($count > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)) {
                    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
                    $p_cat_title = $row['p_cat_title'];
                    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$p_cat_title</option>";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: please check in console did you get any error there?

Comment: how to check in console sir

Comment: just press f12 you will have a tab just beside inspect in your browser

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) this is error displayed on the console

Comment: excetly you have written wrong syntax of ajax

Comment: sir can you write the right syntax ajex .please sir

Comment: and  please change the spell, its not ajex its **ajax**

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cat').on('change',function(){
        var cat_id = $(this).val();
        $.get("ajex.php",{cat:cat_id},function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#subcat').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<select name="cat" class="form-control"  id="cat">
    <option> Select  a Product Category </option>
</select>
```

**ajex.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

if(isset($_GET['cat']) && !empty($_GET['cat'])) {
    include("includes/db.php");
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];
    $query = "select * from bass_categories where cat_id= '$cat_id' ";
    $do = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($do);
    $options = '';    
    if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $p_cat_title = $row['p_cat_title'];
            $options.="<option value='$cat_id'>$p_cat_title</option>";
        }
    } else {
        $options = "<option value=''>Data not found.</option>";
    }
    echo $options;
}

?>
```

Please check the above code

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ this link of code error display (uncaught syntax error)

Comment: do u have another function on the page?

Comment: I don't understand why you getting this error please clear all the errors from console make a refresh with ctrl+shift+r and please make sure you have copied code correctly then check

Comment: now error has gone sir. prb is i havn't insert the jquery.min at the top

Comment: but the sub category is not fill on the dropdown box sir

Comment: have u taken the select option with **subcat** id on your view?

Comment: again i have updated the code please do copy and let me know what you get in console.

Comment: yes sir this is coding <select name="subcat" class="form-control" id="subcat" >  </select> but not working

Comment: check in network you will get some output from ajex.php what is it

Comment: please check your ajex.php is working or not i think there is some problem in ajex.php check manually in url like ajex.php?cat_id=1 or any id that have data

Comment: you said correct sir ajex.php is not working  http://localhost/ganudenufinalnew/admin_area/ajex.php?cat_id=1 .

Comment: i can not access your local host page try to check with error reporting on on this page

Comment: how to check the error reporting error i am beginner of ajex please help sir

Comment: just after your php tag <?php  error_reporting(-1); and ini_set("display_errors", true);

Comment: might be `$options .="<option value='$cat_id'>$p_cat_title</option>";` concating is the issue here, `.`

Comment: remove the space before . and did you get any error on this page?

Comment: ajex.php is not working error are not displayed . display error is ON

Comment: you are passing cat_id from ajax and try to getting cat on ajex.php that why you are not getting out put i have update the answer copy the ajax portion

Comment: still sub category dropdown is not loading sir

Comment: are you getting output on directly? just like the link you send me before?

Comment: once you get output there then you just need to remove the error reporting from top